# Sphinx, how to mirror README.rst and index.rst

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Using sphinx, how can I have my README.rst in the root of my git repository be included in my index.rst in my sphinx docs?  I am using apidoc and autodoc.  A great example is APScheduler, if you look you'll notice that their docs/index.rst is nearly identical to their README.rst

https://bitbucket.org/agronholm/apscheduler/src/11c5c1e7b8c3?at=2.1

Comment: I simply copy-paste by hand, as they have little bit different content. Example: https://bitbucket.org/miohtama/cryptoassets

Answer (score 0):

I do this by having the source directory for the documentation be the root of the project. Then doc/index.rst can refer to README.rst as /README by either including or putting it into a toctree.